# Compile error: could not deduce template argument

Tags: c++, function, class, templates

I am trying to finish a school project of mine, but I have run into a problem. I am trying to use templates in my work, but it seems I don't really understand how to do that. Here a part of my code:

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Osztaly.h"
#include "Fuggvenyek.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){ 
    char kepzes = setKepzes();  
    //diakokBeolvasasa(kepzes);
    diakokKiirasa(kepzes, diakokBeolvasasa(kepzes));
    return 0;
}
```

Fuggvenyek.h

```
#ifndef FUGGVENYEK_H
#define FUGGVENYEK_H

char setKepzes();

template <class szak>
szak diakokBeolvasasa(char);

template <class szak>
void diakokKiirasa(char, szak);

#endif
```

So I am trying to pass back different type of values depending on an if statement.
DiakokKiirasa function then should receieve it as a second argument, and use it to write out some other stuff.

Fuggvenyek.cpp

```
#include "Fuggvenyek.h"
#include "Osztaly.h"
using namespace std;

char setKepzes(){
    char kepzes;
    cout << "A beolvasando szemely kivalasztott kepzese:\n    i - informatikus"
        << "g - gepesz\n>> ";
    cin >> kepzes;
    return kepzes;
}

template <class szak>
szak diakokBeolvasasa(char kepzes){
    I33 informatikusok;
    G22 gepeszek;
    //ha a kepzese informatikus
    if (kepzes == 'i'){
        informatikusok.setDiakokSzama();        
        informatikusok.setDiakAdatok();
        return informatikusok;
    }
    //ha a kepzese gepesz
    else if (kepzes == 'g'){
        gepeszek.setDiakokSzama();
        gepeszek.setDiakAdatok();       
        return gepeszek;
    }
}

template <class szak>
void diakokKiirasa(char kepzes, szak diakok){
        diakok.getDiakAdatok();
}
```

My compile errors:

```
Error   1   error C2783: 'szak diakokBeolvasasa(char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'szak'  d:\programming\c++\cppproject\cppproject\main.cpp   10  1   CppProject
Error   2   error C2780: 'void diakokKiirasa(char,szak)' : expects 2 arguments - 1 provided d:\programming\c++\cppproject\cppproject\main.cpp   10  1   CppProject
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generic template definitions have to be in the same file as their declarations. And there's no way to deduce a template argument from the return type.

Comment: So there is no way to use templates like this?

Comment: The best I can give you is the posted answer, but you still have to move the definitions unless you want linker errors.

Comment: Off-topic: The hungarian naming sounds funny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the compiler to deduce template arguments, these template arguments have to depend on function parameter types. In your case

```
template <class szak>
szak diakokBeolvasasa(char);
```

template argument does not depend on function parameter type. For this reason, it is not possible for the compiler to deduce template arguments for this function. (The compiler cannot deduce template argument from function return type.)

When calling this function you will have to specify template arguments explicitly, as in

```
diakokBeolvasasa<double>(kepzes);
```

Use whatever type you wanted your `szak` to be in place of `double` in the above example.

There is another potential issue with your `diakokBeolvasasa` function. It seems to return a result of either `I33` or `G22` type. If these types are unrelated, then... well... it can't be done that way. There's no such thing as function that can return an "unpredictable" type in C++. And templates won't help you here. So, are `I33` or `G22` somehow related or not?

The second error is just a product of the first.

P.S. As it has been noted in the comments, you should not place template definitions into `.cpp` files. Templates have to be defined in header files.

Comment: Thanks for the help! They are not, but I have made a workaround. I am just calling the function two seperate times once with I33 and second time with G22, this way the compiler knows what it should return to the calling function.

Comment: You could define them in .inl files though.

Comment: @user2176127: Yes, but then you'd have to include these `.inl` files wherever you want to use the functions. The end effect would be the same as defining them in header files. But for code organization purposes one might indeed decide to define them in separate includable files (like `.inl` or such).